# How to test NSLocale return value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nslocale

I am using NSLocale to determine my current country and then pass it as an argument to my web service but i can't test other countries such as Africa etc. through this.
Is there a way to test this?
I am doing this to get the country name:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
    NSString *countryName = [locale displayNameForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode value: countryCode];
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [NSLocale class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers] returns an NSArray of strings of locales the device understands. Each of these can be passed to [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:aString] to give you a locale to test with.

Comment: Ok i got it my other question is will this get the country as India if the user is in India no matter what. Because what i am trying to do is to pass the country name in which the user in (he could be traveller too.)

Comment: That is a separate question - if my answer is correct mark it and create a new one

Comment: NSLocale stores information about interface language and metrics. It don't have nothing common with reverse geocoding which you should use t find exactly user location.